Is it possible to DDoS a web server if we have a poor low connection?
Technically is it possible if I have for example 300 kbps in upload and want to DDoS a 10Gbps web server (that I own for educational purposes)?

DDOS = Distributed DOS. If you want to distribute the packets you need more computers.

Is it possible?  Sort of.  There was a well known DoS attack called Slowloris.

Slowloris tries to keep many connections to the target web server open and hold them open as long as possible. It accomplishes this by opening connections to the target web server and sending a partial request. Periodically, it will send subsequent HTTP headers, adding to, but never completing, the request. Affected servers will keep these connections open, filling their maximum concurrent connection pool, eventually denying additional connection attempts from clients.1

Here is a video explanation and walkthrough of it on YouTube.
This particular vulnerability has been patched.  However, that doesnt mean there are others that are unknown.
Also, you mean DoS (Denial of Service).  A DDoS (Distributed Denial of Service) requires more than one machine.
